# Simple JS function not working in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to use this simple javascript code in my Play Application : http://jsfiddle.net/JXW29/

It does work in my browser, but not in my Play App while I have some animated menus using jQuery which does work well..
Here's the end of my main.scala.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("js/jquery.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("js/functions.js")"></script>
```

Both scripts are in the public/js repository.
I can see, via Firebug, that both scripts are loaded in my browser.

I'm using the last version of Play Framework and jQuery.

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Can you share the field definitions from your view (are they identical to the ones in your jsfiddle?)

Comment: First what you should do is checking the error console, probably it has ready answer for you or at least some clue

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know that an error console was existing..
I got a "TypeError: $ is not a function" from using this code :
(function() {
    $(function() {
        return $("span.deleteItem").bind('click', function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('td').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                return $(this).parents('tr:first').remove();
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
}).call(this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this code :

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    return $("span.deleteItem").bind('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td').fadeOut(1000, function () {
            return $(this).parents('tr:first').remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

from a blog post I found : http://codeimpossible.com/2010/01/13/solving-document-ready-is-not-a-function-and-other-problems/

But I sill don't understand why the former function was working outside of play, and why this one is now working..

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a timing issue - are you using `$(function(){ });` or `.ready()`? When I run your code with the following, it works (compiled from coffeescript):

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    return $("span.deleteItem").bind('click', function() {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('td').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        return $(this).parents('tr:first').remove();
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

My view looks like this - (your directory name is slightly different):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/functions2.js")"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr><td><span class="deleteItem">Click</span></td><td>Test 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="deleteItem">Click</span></td><td>Test 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="deleteItem">Click</span></td><td>Test 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="deleteItem">Click</span></td><td>Test 4</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried both $(function(){ }); and .ready() but still nothing.

Comment: I'm using the exact same code I provided in my jsfiddle, in <body></body> tags, nothing more.

I also tried the exact same code you gave me in my "functions.js".

Comment: if you set a breakpoint (I'm using chrome) on the line starting $(this) does it fire?